# JavaScript Gallery glitch (layers??)

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery

Hope someone can help me, I have an `index.php` setup and in the head I have a sideshow script set and this runs on all pages, and then in the `portfolio.html` (loads inside the `index.php` file when that page is called up)  I have a gallery script. 
My problem is when I click on a gallery image it opens up but behind this "header gallery" ...

image of what the problem is:

[image: http://gem.jamesfaith.com/java.jpg]

Comment: The fade slideshow script is setting the z-index for `.gallerylayer` higher than the lightbox. The easiest (although not necessarily best) fix would be to set the lightbox z-index higher, `#lightbox { z-index: 2000 }`

Comment: @pjumble I've changed the z-index value in viauallightbox.css and nothing seemed to work and then i changed the fadeslideshow.js to 1 and it works, thanks for the help mate !!!

Comment: On your site `visuallightbox.css` is giving `#lightbox` a `z-index` of 100, `.gallerylayer` has a z-index of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

@pjumble is right about wanting to change the z-index. The problem you're having is probably related to the CSS Selectors priority.

When defining a CSS format you can write the selector statement in 3 basic ways and mix and match these as you please for advance selector definitions. Here are the 3 basic ways,

1.

Class's Looks something like this.

```
.class1
{
 color:blue;
 font-size: 24px;
 background-color:red;
}
```

this is the Lowest priority

2.

ID's Looks something like this.

```
 #id1
{
 color:yellow;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

This is medium priority

3.
Tag's look something like this.

```
Div
{
 color:green;
}
```

This one gets highest priority. This always seems counter intuitive to me. If I define and ID level format you think that would have priority over the one for that Tag name but it doesn't.

Here's and example of what I'm talking about.

So for an element like this

```
<Div id="id1" class="class1">
Text
</div>
```

The "Text" here is going to have a red background because "class1" is the only definition with a background-color.

But both "id1" and "class1" have definitions for font-size so the class definition is ignored and the id one is used making "Text" 12px.

Then all three definitions have "color" defined and the winner is "Div" making "Text" green.

so when you write your set up like this,

> #lightbox a z-index of 100, .gallerylayer has a z-index of 1000

you have the right idea but your definition for ".gallerylayer" is a class and if the tag or id of that section of code has `z-index` defined, your class definition of `z-index = 1000;` will be ignored.

Just to make sure the definitions not ignored I'd give the tag that has `class='gallerylayer'` in it and add a `id='somethingUnique'` attribute and use that to define the z-index rule.

But the best way to check this is to use Firefox with the [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) add-on and use the element selecting tool to see what styles are being apply and which are begin ignored on your page.

For more on selectors try looking [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) it should give you all the documentation you'll need.

hope this helps.